# How to return to React app after Steam OpenID authentication with Rails API including response data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, omniauth, rails-api

I am using Rails 6 and React. First step in registration on my platform is signing in through Steam. I got that to work but now when I redirect the user to `localhost:3000/auth/steam` which is the route provided by `omniauth-steam` gem it creates a new user but I don't know how to redirect it back to React with the data about that newly created user.

In React I just have a simple function that redirects user when he click on `Sign in with Steam` buttom:

```js
const _steamLogin = () => {
    window.location.replace(`${backend_url}/auth/steam`)
}
```

And this is the controller in Rails that handles the callback after user has successfully logged in with Steam account:

```rb
class SteamController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :auth_callback

  def auth_callback
    # Get Steam user data
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    # Create new Application
    application = Application.new(steam_uid: auth['uid'], birthday_date: DateTime.now.to_date)
    if application.save
      render json: application, status: 201
    else
      render json: application.errors.full_messages, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

To understand it better without me going deep into my application logic, `Application` is the `User` model.

Finally, the problem is how to redirect back to React after `auth_callback` has finished either successfully or with errors so I can display the success message or the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any knowledge on Rails but I think use simple way to do this,
you can use one variable and set and unset this variabale and replace url after see this variable have true state, you have more ways to redirect page to you website after logged in;

loggedin > log = true
not logged > log = false